# Creating an iOS app from pdf document

Tags: ipad, ios, pdf

So I have a pdf document about 100 pages long that I want to convert into an app and publish it on the app store. I'd be happy to have pagination, indexing and some common features that are out on iPhone books these days.

On my research on the topic I did come across CGPDFDocument, but not sure if I really have to use it or I could get around using something simpler that I could do it in maybe 1-2 days. CGPDFDocument sounds too overwhelming for my app. 
Please direct me if you have any idea on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I followed this tutorial http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-xxx-developing-iphone and submitted my app but unfortunately it was rejected after 15 days of review process. Now I think the only way out is to use one of these tools http://bakerframework.com/